# c++ OpenGL FBX model not loaded properly

Tags: c++, opengl, fbx

I'm trying to load FBX models using OpenGL, I got the importer to work and read the mesh data so I can draw it
[but some parts are not displayed correctly.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBycS.png)

Here's what I use

```
FbxMesh*mesh = pNode->GetMesh();
    //================= Get Vertices ====================================
    int numVerts = mesh->GetControlPointsCount();
    for(int j = 0; j < numVerts; j++)
    {
        FbxVector4 vert = mesh->GetControlPointAt(j);
        vertices[numVertices].x=(float)vert.mData[0];
        vertices[numVertices].y=(float)vert.mData[1];
        vertices[numVertices++].z=(float)vert.mData[2];
        printf("MeshVert: x: %f y: %f z: %f\n", vertices[numVertices-1].x, vertices[numVertices-1].y, vertices[numVertices-1].z);
    }
    //================= Get Indices ====================================
    numIndices = mesh->GetPolygonVertexCount();
    int triangleCount = numIndices / 3;
    indices = new int[numIndices];
    indices = mesh->GetPolygonVertices();
    printf("numIndices: %i\n", numIndices);
    printf("TriangleCount: %i\n", triangleCount);
    //================= Get Normals ====================================
    FbxGeometryElementNormal*normalEl = mesh->GetElementNormal();
    if(normalEl)
    {
        int numNormals = mesh->GetPolygonCount()*3;
        normals = new float[numNormals*3];
        int vertexCounter = 0;
        for(int polyCounter = 0 ; polyCounter<mesh->GetPolygonCount(); polyCounter++)
        {
            for(int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
            {
                FbxVector4 normal = normalEl->GetDirectArray().GetAt(vertexCounter);
                normals[vertexCounter*3+0] = (float)normal[0];
                normals[vertexCounter*3+1] = (float)normal[1];
                normals[vertexCounter*3+2] = (float)normal[2];
                //cout<<"\n"<<normals[vertexCounter*3+0]<<" "<<normals[vertexCounter*3+1]<<" "<<normals[vertexCounter*3+2];
                vertexCounter++;
            }
        }
    }
```

And primitives to draw

```
for(int i = 0; i < numIndices - 3; i++)
{
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glNormal3f(normals[i*3+0], normals[i*3+1], normals[i*3+2]); 
    for(int j = i; j <= i + 2; j++)
    {
        glVertex3f(vertices[indices[j]].x, vertices[indices[j]].y, vertices[indices[j]].z);
        glColor3f(0.3f, 0.3f, 0.3f);
    }
    glEnd();
}
```

Just wondering if anyone can help get this to work.

The rest of my projects code is in https://github.com/buttburger/FBXEssentials/tree/master/OpenGL2

Comment: Your primitive draw is treating the vertex data as if it's a triangle strip. The first triangle uses indices 0, 1 and 2. The second triangle uses vertices 1, 2 and 3. And so on.

I suspect that either your outer loop should be incrementing 'i' by 3, or your inner loop should be multiplying 'i' by 3 just like you do for the normals.

Comment: Thanks a million, I've done as you instructed and incremented 'i' by 3 on the outer loop and got exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it up now

```
for(int i = 0; i < numIndices - 3; i+=3)
{
    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES);
    glNormal3f(normals[i*3+0], normals[i*3+1], normals[i*3+2]);
    for(int j = i; j <= i + 2; j++)
    {
        glVertex3f(vertices[indices[j]].x, vertices[indices[j]].y, vertices[indices[j]].z);
        glColor3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    }
}
glEnd();
glFlush();
glutSwapBuffers();
```